# How to re-render NavBar when a parameter is changed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to re-render nav-bar when user login or sign out.
In my login component, I change the `IsSignIn` parameter value.

Here is my NavBar component:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse @NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            @if (IsSignIn == false)
            {
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Account/Login">Login</NavLink>
            }
            else
            {
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Account/Profile">Profile</NavLink>
            }

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I also want to have a notification component in the NavBar. I want to change notification count from another component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET 8 offers sections. using sections, we can overcome this problem. For more information about sections see: [ASP.NET Core Blazor sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections).

In the following code, I define the LoginMenu content in a `SectionContent` in the `MainLayout`. The `SectionContent` provides content for the corresponding `SectionOutlet` in `NavBar` component.

NavBar.razor:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse @NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <SectionOutlet SectionName="LoginMenu"></SectionOutlet>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
<div class="page" style="flex-direction: column;">
    <main>
        <NavMenu />
        <HeaderComponent />
        @if (IsSignIn == false)
        {
            <SectionContent SectionName="LoginMenu"> 
              <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Account/Login">Login</NavLink>
            </SectionContent>  
        }
        else
        {
            <SectionContent SectionName="LoginMenu">
               <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Account/Profile">Profile</NavLink>
            </SectionContent>  
        }
        
        <article class="content">
            @Body
        </article>

        <Footer />
    </main>
</div>
@code{
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        IsSignIn = await loginService.IsSignIn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a service for rendering different children based on events. The purpose of the service is to raise events between components.

```
public class ChildRenderService
{
    public Action OnLogginChanged { get; set; }

    public void RequestLogginChanged()
    {
        OnLogginChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

On your `NavBar` you can watch the event.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _childRenderService.OnLogginChanged += StateChangedFromChild;
}

private async void StateChangedFromChild()
{
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

And in your login component request the change after loggin in.

```
_childRenderService.RequestLogginChanged();
```

And off course, don't forget to add the service to DI.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ChildRenderService>();
```