# Blazor Web App (.NET 8) - Auto Load all the connected clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor. Recently I have been started developing a Blazor Web App (with .NET 8) (Interactive mode Server only).

Let's assume I'm on **Products** page, and perform any of CRUD operations (add/edit/delete).
What I want is the changes to be automatically reflected in all clients, without being refreshing the page if they are in the same (products) page.

For example, if I (someone) update a product, the changes updated be reflected in all clients (who are currently viewing all products or the current product). Similarly, if deleted, should be removed automatically from the list (without refreshing). If new product is added it should be automatically displayed/added to their list.

I guess it can be achieved via SignalR or Hub, but I am wondering how can I achieve it (the auto load).

Comment: Take a look at this answer that shows how to use the Notification pattern to update a set of clients from a singleton service. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76171327/13065781.  In you case you may need to pass record identities for updating individual record views.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you so much, I will give a try. What about the changes (Add, Delete and Update) on list/products page.

Comment: Any change triggers a RecordChanged event where you can pass the record id, and a ListChanged event to trigger a list refresh.  You won't be able to update individual items in a list.