Problems with reactivness using blazor c#
Hi guys basically I have two individual components, I'm trying to send a list of reports from the first component to the second one for that I've created a global state so that i can share data among components, the issue is that I have a problem with the reactivness of my second component the list that I'm using is beeing updated but i have to force the renderization (adding something in the code of the second component like a comment for example) of my second component so that the table where I'm using the list shows a new record
This is the function that creates a new record in my first component
public partial class WellReportModal {

     public void generateReport() {
        string reportId = selectedWell.FieldName + selectedWell.LeaseName + 
        selectedWell.WellName + selectedWell.Completion + actionDate.ToString();
        reportId = reportId.Replace("-", "")
                   .Replace(" ", "")
                   .Replace("/", "")
                   .Replace(":", "")
                   .Replace("p.m.", "")
                   .Replace("a.m.", "");

        GlobalStateProvider.WellReport newReport = new WellReport();
        
        newReport.Actions = "Actions";
        newReport.ReportId = reportId;
        newReport.FieldName = selectedWell.FieldName;
        newReport.LeaseName = selectedWell.LeaseName;
        newReport.WellName = selectedWell.WellName;
        newReport.Completion = selectedWell.Completion;
        newReport.AnalysisDate = actionDate;
        newReport.PayoutTime = economicTableList[5].Actual;
        newReport.Recommendations = recommendations;
        newReport.Status = wellStatus;
        
        globalStateProvider.AddReport(newReport);
    }
}

In my global state i have something like this to updated the List
public partial class GlobalStateProvider
{

    public List<WellReport> WellReports { get; private set; } = new List<WellReport>();

    public event Action? OnReportAdded;

    public void AddReport(WellReport report)
    {
        WellReports.Add(report);
        OnReportAdded?.Invoke();
    }
}

And in my second component I'm using the List for a Table
public partial class WellReports {
    [CascadingParameter] public GlobalStateProvider globalStateProvider { get; set; }
    
}

        <MudTable Items="@globalStateProvider.WellReports">
               <HeaderContent>
                   <MudTh>Actions</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Report Date</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Report Id</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Urgency</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Recommendations</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Payout Time</MudTh>
               </HeaderContent>
                <RowTemplate>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Actions">@context.Actions</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Report Date">@context.AnalysisDate</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Report Id">@context.ReportId</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Urgency">@context.Status.ToString()</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Recommendations">@context.Recommendations</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Payout Time">@context.PayoutTime</MudTd>
                </RowTemplate>
           </MudTable>

Does anyone know how to magane properly the reactiveness of blazor so that when a new record is created the second component recognizes the change in the List and updated the state of my component without forcing it?

You need to implement the notification pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256650/i-need-to-update-state-of-blazor-component-when-other-component-changed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170542/web-event-handling-in-multiple-windows-blazor

GlobalStateProvider Should be a registered service in order to inject it in your second component class:
//Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<GlobalStateProvider>();

Your second component needs to subscribe to the event OnReportAdded raized with the AddReport method, most likely should be done in the second component's OnInitialized() lifecycle method, here is an example:
In your component's razor.cs class:
public partial class WellReports {
    [inject] public GlobalStateProvider globalStateProvider; // no getter or setter  
}

Or directly in your .razor file:
@implements IDisposable
@inject GlobalStateProvider globalStateProvider


        <MudTable Items="@globalStateProvider.WellReports">
               <HeaderContent>
                   <MudTh>Actions</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Report Date</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Report Id</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Urgency</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Recommendations</MudTh>
                   <MudTh>Payout Time</MudTh>
               </HeaderContent>
                <RowTemplate>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Actions">@context.Actions</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Report Date">@context.AnalysisDate</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Report Id">@context.ReportId</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Urgency">@context.Status.ToString()</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Recommendations">@context.Recommendations</MudTd>
                   <MudTd DataLabel="Payout Time">@context.PayoutTime</MudTd>
                </RowTemplate>
           </MudTable>

@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized(){
        //Subscribe to the event
        globalStateProvider.OnReportAdded += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        //Make sure to unsubscribe
        globalStateProvider.OnReportAdded -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}

Here you can see the second component is waitintg for the OnReportAdd event to be raized by handling it and invoking StateHasChanged().
the Dispose lifecycle method (implemented from IDisposable) handles disposing the subscription when the application kills/disposes of the second component.
